# sql query for apache airflow

Tags: sql, airflow

i would like to query the apache airflow database directly for a report of failed tasks, but i'm struggling with the appropriate join to make in the database.

what i would like is an output consisting of the following columns

`dag_run.dag_id
dag_run.run_id
dag_run.state
dag_run.conf
task_instance.task_id
task_id.state`

basically a sql dump of all dag_runs and the status of their tasks; similar to the 'Graph' view but all all run_ids.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the query for information about your failed task.

```
SELECT dr.dag_id, dr.run_id, dr.state, dr.conf, ti.task_id, ti.state
FROM dag_run as dr
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT dag_id, task_id, state, execution_date
    FROM task_instance
    WHERE state = 'failed'
) as ti
ON dr.dag_id = ti.dag_id AND dr.execution_date = ti.execution_date
```

I don't know what you want, but you can use DAG's `on_failure_callback` parameter to set it to do something when it fails. I recommend using this method.